What is wrong with my relativistic explanation of the bucket argument by Newton?
Newton's bucket argument in my view:
Time dilation is greater at the outer edge of the rotating bucket according to special relativity. This is analogous to gravity in the classical limit. As a result, it pulls the water outward, reducing the water level at the inner part of the bucket, the central radial point, where there is less "gravity" due to the absence of time dilation.
Thus, special relativity, in the form of general relativity, explains Mach's thought experiment and Newton's bucket problem.
Can anybody possibly explain what would be wrong with my previous reasoning?

If you add some equations, your point will be more clear.

unless the bucket is rotating at relativistic speeds, time dilation would be negligible. That kills your argument.

Also maybe explain what you mean by "the bucket argument by Newton?" Isaac Newton? I don't see how Newton could have possible made an argument about general relativity...

@PatoGalmarini Negligible ≠ zero. Who are we to judge how much time dilation it takes to create a force equal to the centrifugal force? The constant of big G has not been explained, or even accurately measured

@ClaudioSaspinski That of course is the main point, but I thought to post it here to get a quick jist of what people think and how they respond. I am thinking out loud here obviously; Mach nor Einstein solved this problem either I believe...

if the water moves at 10m/sec, way above that in any bucket, teh time dilation factor would be  1.0000000000000005. Do you seriously think that will affect gravity so much?

Gravity is due to spacetime curvature, not time dilation.

What is wrong with your argument is that you have failed to include any kind of quantitative modelling to show that the extent of the observed rise in the level of the water at the edge of the bucket can be accounted for by a relativistic effect.
That said, anyone with a modicum of common sense would realise that time dilation cannot be the cause.

Thanks, anyone with a modicum of common sense would not even know what time dilation is ;-)

What is wrong with your claim is that it you haven't explained what problem you're trying to solve or how your solution fixes that problem.
There are some reasons to think that your statements can't explain the curvature of water in a rotating bucket. One problem is that for a bucket rotating at a few metres per second time dilation effects will be negligible: $(v/c)^2\approx 10^{-16}$ and time dilation will be related to $\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}\approx 1-2(v/c)^2 \approx 1$ where the second step uses the Taylor expansion of the square root.
Another odd feature of your question is that you appear to have made no effort to look up the literature on the bucket experiment and relativity. See for example these discussions of the evolution of Einstein's views on the bucket experiment
https://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/8605/
https://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/4377/
There are also textbooks on relativity that explain what general relativity claims about inertial frames, such as "Gravity" by James B. Hartle.
